# Refresh macOS GUI without logging out

Tags: macos, gui

My macOS 10.12 has a strange phenomena since 3 days:

- Everything on the screen is not responding with my mouse: 3 buttons control of windows don't show its icons on mouse hover, any element in the windows is not responding with mouse hover.
- Middle mouse is not working anymore: cannot close browser tabs or open link in new tab.
- Mission control is accessible, however, cannot switch space.
- Dock icons are not moving on mouse move.
- The mouse doesn't change its form when moving to other windows or another monitor, it sticks on its form to the last focused window.

The phenomena is gone as long as I log out and re log in. That takes me 1-2min, not as much but I don't want to lose all my work spaces, nor to restart my docker containers, etc. everytime. On Windows, I think we have to restart the `explorer` process to refresh the GUI.

What I've had before the bug occurs:

- Skype
- Firefox (~10-20 opened tabs)
- Sublime Text
- iTerm2
- VirtualBox with a 1GB RAM running docker-machine.
- Telegram
- Docker: 4 containers.

All my applications are up-to-date. Thanks in advance.

What my log showed at the moment that the bug occurs.

```
error   15:33:04.283037 +0700   WindowServer    CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 85671
error   15:33:04.283104 +0700   WindowServer    CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 85671
error   15:33:04.283150 +0700   WindowServer    CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 85671
error   15:33:04.283190 +0700   WindowServer    CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 85671
error   15:33:31.727778 +0700   symptomsd   AWDAgent: failed create new libnetcore metric for 0x290007
error   15:35:18.093791 +0700   parsecd network_config_has_proxies_configured network_config_has_proxies_configured is deprecated
error   15:35:18.093835 +0700   parsecd tcp_connection_get_remote API Misuse: Function must be called after tcp_connection_start
error   15:35:18.093904 +0700   parsecd tcp_connection_is_cellular API Misuse: Function must be called after tcp_connection_start
error   15:35:18.110774 +0700   parsecd network_config_has_proxies_configured network_config_has_proxies_configured is deprecated
error   15:35:18.110813 +0700   parsecd tcp_connection_get_remote API Misuse: Function must be called after tcp_connection_start
error   15:35:18.110908 +0700   parsecd tcp_connection_is_cellular API Misuse: Function must be called after tcp_connection_start
error   15:35:18.530763 +0700   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
error   15:35:18.669932 +0700   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
error   15:35:18.670896 +0700   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
error   15:35:18.959840 +0700   parsecd Server endpoint not set, data can't be sent to server
error   15:35:19.417085 +0700   parsecd keyboardInputMode property not set, using <private>
error   15:35:19.838056 +0700   parsecd Server endpoint not set, data can't be sent to server
error   15:35:19.914901 +0700   parsecd Server endpoint not set, data can't be sent to server
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `killall Finder` in the terminal as a workaround.

If the problem persists you might wanna look inside `/var/log/system.log` for suspicious entries around that time.

Maybe you're lucky and an OS update will "solve" this issue.

Comment: `killall Finder` didn't solve the problem. I just updated my log.